# NameError: name 'permutations' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

This is a script that generates password dictionary for guessing a password.

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "pass.py", line 19, in <module>
  for p in permutations(stuff, x):
     NameError: name 'permutations' is not defined
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# define the prefix to try since we knew what the password starts with
prefix = ['begin', 'Begin']

# list of sequences to run through
sequences = ['seq1', 'Seq1', 'SEQ1', 'se2', '!', '123', '555', '103', '_']

# open the password file where the dictionary will be saved

newfile = open('mypass.txt', 'w')

# A python3 thing I guess
stuff = list(sequences)

# Generate permutations of the password, starting wth the prefix and then 2 to 6 combos of the "charset"
for i in prefix:
  for x in range(2,6):
    for p in permutations(stuff, x):
        newfile.write(''.join(p) + '\n')
```

Example output:

```
beginseq1SEQ1
begin_seq1
Begin_seq1103
```

Comment: Add `from itertools import permutations` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

This `permutations` is probably a function from another file or from a package. Probably you are a new python user and have forgotten to state at the top of your code to which file or package you refer. You have to add a line that looks like this, if you import from a file:

```
from some_code_file.py import some_function
```

or like this, if you import a package:

```
import python_package as py_pa
```

And than your code should work as you have writen it. Or just alter to the form `some_function.permutations(stuff,x)` or `py_pa.permtations(stuff,x)`